# Customizing shiny app with images in header and footer

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I'm customizing a shiny app by adding a header and footer with embedded images. I've figured out how to add the images and customise their position using `tags$styles`. The problem I am having is when trying to change the position of the image in the footer by adjusting the position from the top of the footer panel I also change the position of the image in the header. I know it has something to do with the use of CSS so what I am trying to figure out is how to separate the `tags$style` between the header and the footer. I am not familiar with HTML or CSS so am blundering through this process. The code I am using for the header and footer is below:

```
tags$header(a(list(tags$style("img {display:inline-block;background-repeat:no-repeat;position:relative;left:20px;z-index:3;}"),tags$img(src="myimage.png", height="110px",width="215px")),href="http://www.link1.com"),
                tags$style("header {background-color: #333333;border-bottom:1px solid #474747;
                           height:90px}") 
tags$div(fluidRow(
  tags$footer(a(list(tags$style("img {display:inline-block;background-repeat:no-repeat;position:relative;left:20px;top:30px;z-index:3;}"),
                     tags$img(src="myimage2.png", height="23px",width="170px")),href="http://www.link2.com"),
              tags$style("footer {background-color: #333333;height:90px}"))))
```

Thanks in advance for any help!!